# Why does my FASTA file starts with an empty > symbol?

Tags: r

So I am trying to write into a FASTA file, it does write but for some reason when I open the file it starts with an empty > and then >SOMESEQID and so on. Could someone help?

When opening the file it looks like so:

```
>
>NP_001997.5 fibroblast growth factor 2 isoform 34 kDa [Homo sapiens] MVGVGGGDVEDVTPRPGGCQISGRGARGCNGIPGAAAWEAALPRRRPRRHPSVNPRSRAAGSPRTRGRRT EERPSGSRLGDRGRGRALPGGRLGGRGRGRAPERVGGRGRGRGTAAPRAAPAARGSRPGPAGTMAAGSIT TLPALPEDGGSGAFPPGHFKDPKRLYCKNGGFFLRIHPDGRVDGVREKSDPHIKLQLQAEERGVVSIKGV CANRYLAMKEDGRLLASKCVTDECFFFERLESNNYNTYRSRKYTSWYVALKRTGQYKLGSKTGPGQKAIL FLPMSAKS
```

FGF2 is a vector of ID something like so:

```
FGF2 = c("ID1","ID2", ...)
```

Here is my code:

```
files = entrez_fetch(id = FGF2, rettype = "fasta", db = "protein")
files

fastFile = write.fasta(sequences = files, names = names(files), file.out = "mySeqs.fasta")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `write.fasta` . That function most likely assumes some kind of data. Just use writeLines() :

```
library(rentrez)
a = entrez_fetch(id=c("NP_001997.5","NP_001348594.1"),
rettype = "fasta", db = "protein")
writeLines(a,"test.fa")

readLines("test.fa")
 [1] ">NP_001997.5 fibroblast growth factor 2 isoform 34 kDa [Homo sapiens]"   
 [2] "MVGVGGGDVEDVTPRPGGCQISGRGARGCNGIPGAAAWEAALPRRRPRRHPSVNPRSRAAGSPRTRGRRT"  
 [3] "EERPSGSRLGDRGRGRALPGGRLGGRGRGRAPERVGGRGRGRGTAAPRAAPAARGSRPGPAGTMAAGSIT"  
 [4] "TLPALPEDGGSGAFPPGHFKDPKRLYCKNGGFFLRIHPDGRVDGVREKSDPHIKLQLQAEERGVVSIKGV"  
 [5] "CANRYLAMKEDGRLLASKCVTDECFFFERLESNNYNTYRSRKYTSWYVALKRTGQYKLGSKTGPGQKAIL"  
 [6] "FLPMSAKS"                                                                
 [7] ""                                                                        
 [8] ">NP_001348594.1 fibroblast growth factor 2 isoform 18 kDa [Homo sapiens]"
 [9] "MAAGSITTLPALPEDGGSGAFPPGHFKDPKRLYCKNGGFFLRIHPDGRVDGVREKSDPHIKLQLQAEERG"  
[10] "VVSIKGVCANRYLAMKEDGRLLASKCVTDECFFFERLESNNYNTYRSRKYTSWYVALKRTGQYKLGSKTG"  
[11] "PGQKAILFLPMSAKS"                                                         
[12] ""
```

Or read in using:

```
library(Biostrings)
readAAStringSet("test.fa")
  A AAStringSet instance of length 2
    width seq                                               names               
[1]   288 MVGVGGGDVEDVTPRPGGCQISG...YKLGSKTGPGQKAILFLPMSAKS NP_001997.5 fibro...
[2]   155 MAAGSITTLPALPEDGGSGAFPP...YKLGSKTGPGQKAILFLPMSAKS NP_001348594.1 fi...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: glad it helps :)